# Use of 'city' in Byron's poem "Darkness"

Tags: meaning, poetry, lord-byron

In his poem ["Darkness"](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/43825/darkness-56d222aeeee1b), Lord Byron writes:

> [...]
> The crowd was famish'd by degrees; but two
> Of an enormous city did survive,
> And they were enemies: they met beside
> [...]

Is Byron employing 'city' in a sense similar to 'scope' or 'size' in this instance?

Answer (score 8):

“City” has its usual meaning, “a large or important municipality” (*OED*). The tricky word here is “but”, which Byron uses in the sense “nothing but, no more than, only, merely” (*OED*). So the lines mean that, out of the original population of the enormous city, only two people were left alive: the rest had “famished by degrees” (that is, died of starvation one by one).

Comment: So then 'crowd' in this instance refers to totality of the occupants of said 'enormous city', or does it refer to humanity as a whole which the population of the 'enormous city' are a strict or equal subset of, or is it just not explicitly specified as either?

Comment: "Crowd" could be taken in either sense (or both).